# PHP Associative Array Variable Assignment

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have this code in a larger function that pulls data from an HTTP Post (using Laravel) and puts it into an array for further processing. I feel like there has to be a better way to accomplish putting these fields into an array, but I'm not sure how. Suggestions?

```
    $fields = array(
        'env' => $request->get('env'),
        'subtype' => $request->get('subtype'),
        'submitter' => $request->get('submitter'),
        'problemSummary' => $request->get('problemSummary'),
        'problemDescription' => $request->get('problemDescription'),
        'resolutionCode' => $request->get('resolutionCode'),
        'resolutionDetails' => $request->get('resolutionDetails'),
        'status' => $request->get('status'),
        'account' => $request->get('account'),
        'phone' => $request->get('phone'),
        'residenceHall' => $request->get('residenceHall'),
        'roomNumber' => $request->get('roomNumber'),
        'buildingName' => $request->get('buildingName'),
        'buildingNumber' => $request->get('buildingNumber'),
        'source' => $request->get('source'),
        'submittedVia' => $request->get('submittedVia'),
        'internalNotes' => $request->get('internalNotes'),
        'computerType' => $request->get('computerType'),
        'computerVendor' => $request->get('computerVendor'),
        'operatingSystem' => $request->get('operatingSystem'),
        'recentBackup' => $request->get('recentBackup'),
        'antiVirus' => $request->get('antiVirus'),
        'acceptAgreement' => $request->get('acceptAgreement'),
    );
```

Comment: Define "better way". This looks perfectly fine.

Comment: Doesn't it have an `->all()` method or something like that?

Comment: @FirstOne Yes, there is a $request->all() method but in case of errors from the posting side (extraneous fields, for example) I need to make sure I get only these fields. ->all() will send me everything.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen This works, but at least in my opinion, seems messy. I was considering a loop like zerkms suggested.

Comment: @Ross What is the problem? The code may seem quite "bulky", if you like, but it tells you *exactly* what is happening. A loop would only complicate it. It is always better for code to be straight-forward than for it to do "clever" things because it *looks* better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's wrong with:

```
$fields = $request->only('env', 'subtype', 'submitter', ... );
```

or:

```
$fieldNames = ['env', 'subtype', 'submitter', ...];
$fields = $request->only($fieldNames);
```

Comment: This looks better than my approach. +1

Comment: I had no idea this was a thing! This looks perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
// Define the field names you want to get from the request
/*
$fields = array(
    'env',
    'subtype',
    'submitter',
    ...
);
*/

$data = array();
foreach($fields as $v){
    $data[$v] = $request->get($v);
}
```

It will only get the values from the keys of the request defined in `$fields` and it will put in the same key in the `$data` array.